# Connecting tp4056 in parallel

Tags: battery-charging, parallel

I have a couple of these cheap TP4056 battery charger modules and four 18650 li-ion batteries. I want to use all four of them. Is it possible to connect outputs of these modules in a way shown below (in parallel)? Connecting inputs shouldn't be a problem as far as I know.
[image: Circuit "diagram"]

Comment: how do you cahrge the batteries since tp4056 modules have a usb input each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a problem. This will work OK, as far as you will not connect batteries together (in parallel or serial)

Comment: This is important! OP, you must *not* have any connection between the batteries. I don't know the behaviour of the TP4065, but even having any significant capacity between leads of different batteries might confuse the chargers

Comment: Clearly the schematic in OP's post has no problem, but what about one with all the negatives common on the output side ?

Comment: I am also interested do same circuit, but can this circuit be charged by regular 5V 2A usb wall charger?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should add a diode in Output of each module to avoid any damage because of any of the module's battery is not functional

Answer (score -2):

i recently opened a thread regarding this.
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qqjzp3nj527zk3n/lithium%20ion%20-%20disconnecting%20output%20during%20charging%20-%20Electrical%20Engineering%20Stack%20Exchange.pdf?dl=0)
i'm using 9 18650's in series and dropping it down to create 22V 3A battery pack.

These are things i learned:

1. if you can use chip designed to be used with multiple cells, use it. This is designed to be used on one cell only.
2. if you must use these, you must disconnect positive and negative input between cells when charging, and vice versa(disconnect output + and - when charging) otherwise it won't work (it either blows up, gets really hot or keeps led's on when it shouldn't)
3. i chose to use these because i have random collection of cells, so i cannot make reliable battery pack of those on one controller.
4. disconnecting can be done only with switches or relays, which makes it kinda awkward in size and wire clutter.

here's my "finished product":[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDkmlTGx0sY)

pros:

-huge charging current (1A per cell vs. scrubby few amps on normal chargers) 
 -speedy charging due to current 
 -each cell has it's own charge/discharge protection

cons:

-size 
 -impracticality 
 -cost 

EDIT1: link to deleted post only showed up to me, so i printed it in pdf and put it i my dropbox, so it should work now.

Comment: The first link is not working!

Comment: What a strange looking answer.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question which was asked